# Custom Control Not Responding to jQuery calls In Google Maps Api

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3

can you please take a look at following code and let me know how come I cant push the Google Map Custom Control to call the jquery .click() function? Here is the part to create a map element and assigning a class (.test)

```
var controlDiv = document.createElement('div');
var controlButton = document.createElement('button');
controlButton.setAttribute("class", "btn btn-mini btn-success test");
controlButton.innerHTML = 'Control Button';

controlDiv.appendChild(controlButton);

// Add 'div' containing button to the map
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM].push(controlDiv);

$('.test').click(function () {
    alert("Handler for");
});
```

I already test the code it works out of the Map UI but not in map custom control format!

Comment: Your code is fine, but you aren't giving us very much to look at. My first guess is that you're running the code to attach the click handler (the jQuery code) before you actually add the div to the DOM.

Comment: Hi Adam Thanks for reply, I updated the code and it is all I have after creating the Map part.Can you please let me know what exactly you mean by the end of your comment? _"attach the click handler (the jQuery code) before you actually add the div to the DOM."_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend event delegation. It makes this kind of problem simple. You can use it not only for this Maps API problem, but any situation where you need to respond to events on DOM elements that aren't yet created, such as content loaded with an Ajax call.

Let me assume your map container `<div>` has an `id` of `map_div`.

Then, where you have this code:

```
$('.test').click(function () {
    alert("Handler for");
});
```

change it to:

```
$('#map_div').on( 'click', '.test', function () {
    alert("Handler for");
});
```

How this works: instead of attaching the event handler to the not-yet-created `.test` element, it's attached to the map container, which should already exist—but the event handler function still responds only to clicks on your `.test` element once it's created.

The code above is for jQuery 1.7+. For 1.4.2+ it would be:

```
$('#map_div').delegate( '.test', 'click', function () {
    alert("Handler for");
});
```

Comment: Thanks Michael, it works now but to be honest I am still a little confused! isn't' the "controlButton" created by using the **var controlButton = document.createElement('button');** if not so what is the rule of **createElement()** function then?

Comment: For me, it seems that map.controls[...].push() does not immediately add the elements to DOM and thus jQuery is unable to bind the click event handler.

Answer (score 3):

If you wait until the map is idle (finished rendering), then the button is part of the DOM and the jquery selector works:

```
var controlDiv = document.createElement('div');
var controlButton = document.createElement('button');
controlButton.setAttribute("class", "btn btn-mini btn-success test");
controlButton.innerHTML = 'Control Button';

controlDiv.appendChild(controlButton);

// Add 'div' containing button to the map
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM].push(controlDiv);

google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function() {$('.test').click(function () {
      alert("Handler for");
    });
});
```

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_simpleMap_buttonClickJquery.html)

Comment: Thanks geocodezip, I didn't want to combine both addListenerOnce and jquery way. As you are fully aware we can even do this by using the **google.maps.event.addListenerOnce()** method. by the way thanks for letting me know your approach and example

Comment: But do you understand _why_ it works?  That is what you need to make your version work.

Comment: I still didnt get the point of 'idle' in your code.I am using the code inside a jquery document.ready() function and I was assuming that all DOM and elements should be loaded fully inside this function as Code included inside **$( document ).ready()** will only run **once the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute**.So why this is happening here? kind of confusing!

Comment: Because the map is being initialized in that same ready event, and isn't done initializing until the first 'idle'.  The controls are added to the map (and the DOM) as part of the map's initialization.

Comment: Thanks I think I know what was happening now. Once again thanks. by the way do you think you have time to take a look at this post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16881810/getting-the-name-of-bus-stop-in-the-info-windows) as well?